# Error on C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; declspec(noreturn)differs"

Tags: c++

I keep having this error "Error 1 error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; declspec(noreturn)differs" whenever I tried to compile the following codes. I also tried the online solution by either move the glut to the end or move stdlib.h to the top. But it is still not working. 
Appreciate your help! I'm using visual Studio 2012, cpp.

This is the loop.cpp:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "loop.h"

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
HWND hwnd;
MSG Msg;


wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style         = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}


hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    g_szClassName,
    "The title of my window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

if(hwnd == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);


while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
return Msg.wParam;
}

**This is object.cpp:**

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "loop.h"
#include <windows.h>

HINSTANCE hInstance;
HINSTANCE hPrevInstance;
LPSTR lpCmdLine;
int nCmdShow;

HWND hwnd;
UINT msg;
WPARAM wParam;
LPARAM lParam;

void screen_keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
char* name = 0;
Vertex* vertex;
long lines = 0;

switch (key) {
    case 'W':
    case 'w':
        wire = !wire;
        break;
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        refine(we);
        unitize(we);
        facetNormals(we);
        printf("%d Faces.\n", faceCount(we));
        break;
    case 'S':
    case 's':
        subdivide(we);
        unitize(we);
        facetNormals(we);
        printf("%d Faces.\n", faceCount(we));
        break;
    case 'L':
    case 'l':
        subdivide(we); 
        refine(we);
        unitize(we);
        facetNormals(we);
        printf("%d Faces.\n", faceCount(we));
        break;
    case 'B':
    case 'b':
        subdivideButt(we);
        refine(we);
        unitize(we);
        facetNormals(we);
        break;
    case 'D':
    case 'd':
        name = "data/drum.obj";
        break;
    case 'Z':
    case 'z':
        name = "data/ball.obj";
        break;
    case 'H':
    case 'h':
        name = "data/sphere.obj";
        break;
    case 'E':
    case 'e':
        name = "data/equilateraltri.obj";
            break;
    case 'U':
    case 'u':
        name = "data/cube.obj";
        break;
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
        name = "data/prism.obj";
        break;
    case 'C':
    case 'c':
        name = "data/cylinder.obj";
        break;
    case 'T':
    case 't':
        name = "data/isoscelestri.obj";
        break;
    case 'O':
    case 'o':
        name = filename;
        break;
    case 'I':
    case 'i':
        //Import shape
        WinMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance,lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);
        WndProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        break;  
    case 'X':
    case 'x':
        lines = writeOBJ(we, "output.obj");
        printf("Wrote output.obj (%d lines)\n", lines);
        break;
    case 'V':
    case 'v':
        verify(we);
        break;
    case '1':
        vertex =    we->vertices;
        while (vertex) {
            vertex->newpoint = GL_FALSE;
            vertex = vertex->next;
        }
        firstDivision(we->faces);
        unitize(we);
        facetNormals(we);
        printf("----- First Pass -----\n");
        printf("%d Vertices.\n", vertexCount(we));
        printf("%d Faces.\n\n", faceCount(we));         
        break;
    case 'Q':
    case 'q':
        exit(1);
        break;  
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
        break;
}

if (name) {
    if (we) free(we);
    we = readOBJ(name); 
    if (!we) exit(0);
    unitize(we);
    facetNormals(we);
}

redisplay_all();
}
```

Comment: 8 lines at the top of object.cpp are probably all that is relevant here, you could have removed everything else and still get the same error.

Comment: yupp! I tried and the error is still there. Thanks for your help anyway. @n.m.

Comment: Let me firmulate this a bit more blatantly. Your question contains ~90% irrelevant noise. This reduces your chances to get help by about the same amount.

Comment: That error message usually comes with a file name and a line number. Those *would* be relevant.

Comment: take @n.m.'s advice and filer out the irrelevant details.  And maybe provide the contents of loop.h which you #included prior to windows.h for some reason.